# не компилируется код с ООП в c++ из-за ссылок на bool (я так думаю)

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++, vector

```
...

typedef pair<int, int> cell;
template <typename T>
T& get(vector<vector<T>>& m, cell c) {
    return m[c.first][c.second];
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<bool>> v(5, vector<bool>(5));
    get(v, cell{0, 0}) = true;
    return 0;
}
```

IDE пишет

> Non-const lvalue referenceto type 'bool' cannot bind to a temporary of a type 'std::vector < bool >...'

когда я использую `vector<vector<bool>>`. Возможно ли сделать такую функцию для `bool`?

Comment: У вас же `pair<int, int>` откуда там bool?

Comment: @NewView При чём здесь `cell`? Автор вопроса передаёт `vector<vector<bool>>`, оттуда и `bool`.

Comment: @Arhad, да, верно, смутило `get(...) = true;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что для экономии памяти `vector<bool>` хранит значения в упакованном виде, и обращение к ним идет через специальный прокси-класс.

Попробуйте так:

```
template <typename T>
typename vector<T>::reference get(vector<vector<T>>& m, cell c) {
    return m[c.first][c.second];
}
```

Это должно вас спасти :)

Для обычных типов это будет по сути `T&`, для `bool` - тот самый прокси, который обеспечит присваивание.